# How to replace zk session HttpSession in Java

Tags: java, session, zk

I have a ZK web project that had .zul files with corresponding composers.I am trying to remove .zul files and replacing them by .jsp files.

Please have a look at the following snippet of code and suggest if I can replace them with HttpSession ? Please also let me know if I need to provide further additional information.
Any suggestions/feedbacks/guidance would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

### Code Snippet

```
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Session;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Sessions;

public static void loadUserCustomProperties(String userFolder){
   // Create a properties object with system wide properties as defaults
   Properties userCustomProperties = new Properties(CustomProperties);

  Session session = Sessions.getCurrent();   //Line 5
  session.setAttribute(Constants.USER_PROPERTIES, userCustomProperties);  //Line 6

 }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: question also asked on zk forum(with no info about the jsp) : http://forum.zkoss.org/question/91234/how-can-i-replace-session-in-java/

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: This isn't a code review; he simply wants to know how to share information between HttpSession and ZK's Session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZK just wraps the standard Java HTML/HTTP API.

Calling `Sessions.getCurrent().getNativeSession()` should give you an instance of type `HttpSession`.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Digulla,
It will help me
But, sir my problem is that 
My project has many packages with many of the class file in eclipse.     And each file use ZK session variable but there i can't use session as well as HttpSesstion object..
So what can i do...  
My need is use session in the class file in the eclipse ( not in servlet and jsp)
So if you have any idea so please tell me...

Comment: Please try to be precise. `session` (the JSP variable) with the type `HttpSession` isn't ZK's `Session` type or the `Sessions` helper. So which type do you need and where do you need it?

Comment: Sir please give me your skype id so that i can call you whenever you are free so that i can explain my problem properly.
(If you don't mind)
you can also send your in mail id to my mail chintanlogin@gmail.com
please give me time so that time i will call you..

Comment: I don't use skype. Sit down, produce a complete example of what you want to achieve and edit the question above.

Comment: Update: I had a look at ZK's `org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SimpleSession`. It just wraps a normal `HttpSession`. See my edits.

Comment: We can write java code in 3 types of file
java file, servlet file & jsp file

so that are zk session are used in the java file and that java file how can i use HttpSession instand of zk session

In servlet & jsp file i knew Session
but, in Java file how can i create an object of HttpSession class

Comment: See my edits. Why do you need to use `HttpSession`?

Comment: ohh..k
i see your edits there
i only need replace zk session in from the my file and use some java code there instand of that 2 session lines

Comment: In the project there are use session for set attribute so what i need to write instand of that if you know..

Comment: Sorry i can check your new edits...
I thik that may be work 
I try it that and then say you..
Thank you sir...:)